# Server isn't echoing messages back to clients

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, server

I've been having a major issue with my code that involves using an ArrayList to handle sockets that are connected to the server. What's happening is that, once the client sends a message to the server, the server isn't echoing the message back to all of the clients when it's supposed to. Instead nothing happens.

One thing that is working correctly is that when the client joins the server, the server prints to the clients output stream that they have connected, but whenever the client sends the server a message, nothing happens.

Here is the source code for the Server.class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Server {
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private Thread inputThread;
private Thread acceptThread;

private ArrayList<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList<>();

private final String TITLE = "Server";
private final int WIDTH = 400;
private final int HEIGHT = 300;

private final int PORT = 9999;

private Server() {
    createGUI();
    acceptConnections();
    startInput();
}

private void acceptConnections() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    acceptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    socketList.add(socket);
                    output("Client " + socket.getInetAddress() + " has joined the server.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    acceptThread.start();
}

private void startInput() {
    inputThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (!socketList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < socketList.size(); i++) {
                        Socket socket = socketList.get(i);
                        BufferedReader input;
                        try {
                            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                            String message;
                            while ((message = input.readLine()) != null) {
                                print(message);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    inputThread.start();

    print("Started server successfully.");
}

// private String generateID() {
// StringBuilder id = new StringBuilder();
// Random random = new Random();
// for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
// id.append(random.nextInt(10));
// }
// return id.toString();
// }

private void createGUI() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void output(String message) {
    print(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < socketList.size(); i++) {
        Socket socket = socketList.get(i);
        try {
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output.println(message);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void print(String message) {
    textArea.append(message + "\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();
}
```

}

Here is the source code for the Client.class that connects to the server:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client implements KeyListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField textField;

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader input;
private PrintStream output;
private Thread inputThread;

private final String TITLE = "Client";
private final int WIDTH = 600;
private final int HEIGHT = 500;

private final String IP = "localhost";
private final int PORT = 9999;

private Client() {
    createGUI();
    connect(1);
    startThread();
}

private void connect(int attempt) {
    print("Attempting to connect to server... Attempt #" + attempt);
    try {
        socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        attempt++;
        connect(attempt);
    }
}

private void startThread() {
    inputThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    print(message);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    inputThread.start();
}

private void createGUI() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(this);

    frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void send(String message) {
    output.println(message);
    output.flush();
    textField.setText(null);
}

private void print(String message) {
    textArea.append(message + "\n");
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        send(textField.getText());
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Client();
}
```

}

You can easily copy and paste this code into your own work space since it doesn't require anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally."

This fixes my issue! I think, but I got it from the ArrayList documentation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. `PrintWriter` is buffered. You need to `flush()` after each message if you want it read straight away.
2. Your read loops are incorrect:

   ```
   public void run() {
       while (true) {
           try {
               if (input.ready()) {
                   String message = input.readLine();
                   print(message);
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Change to:

   ```
   public void run() {
       String message;
       try {
           while ((message = input.readLine()) != null) {
               print(message);
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   At present you're smoking the CPU while there is no input, *and* at end of stream, *and* if there is an `IOException.`
3. You need a thread per client. This technique of using a single threads to read from an array of sockets cannot possible work.

Comment: I've added output.flush() to the server and client and it's still not working unfortunately. Any more suggestions or help?

Comment: Ok, I removed the ready calls, but I'm still having trouble echoing messages back to the client. I think it has something to do with using an ArrayList, because I noticed that when I convert the ArrayList to an Object[] then get cast the index to a socket, it seems to work relatively fine, but it is very inefficient having to convert the ArrayList to an Object[] each time I want to write to the client.

Comment: Ok, I just changed the methods that I was using to your suggested strategy for reading, but the server still isn't echoing back to the client once the client sends the message.

Comment: Why would creating a thread for every socket be necessary when I can just use socketList.get(i) which returns a socket that I can write to? Do you have a source on this?

Comment: It won't work because you will block when *reading* any of them, and using `ready()` or `available() > 0` won't prevent that as you are reading lines.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I found the issue as you can see in my answer, since I am using other threads to modify the socket list, and haven't synchronized them.